# Authoring software used to create illustrated Pen&Paper book

Tags: books, publishing, wizards-of-the-coast

At the risk of being somewhat off-topic (sorry but couldn't find any conclusive info on this) ...

What authoring software is recommended to create rich, illustrated books in a similar style as many of the Pen&Paper supplements published by companies like Wizards of the Coast? I'm looking for a software to create layout and design in a similar style, incl. illustrations, tables, quotes, info boxes, etc.

Before you now point me at the usual suspects such as Adobe InDesign, I'm asking this question exactly to find out whether any of the big publishing tools fit the requirement better than others.

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of question asking for tool recommendations is off topic here because it doesn't work well within the format (though that  doesn't mean it is at all a bad question in general). However you may find better success on a forum (see [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) for a list of our recommendations). You may also be interested in [this](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/955897988508827649?s=20) about your specific concern.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Unfortunatly as this is currently written it falls under recommendation/shopping which are [off topic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) ("Whats your favorite ...?").Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: You might have better luck asking in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Welcome to this stack! Your question may be answered by answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45741/8610) or [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/31460/8610). As it stands, this question itself may not fit the site, but with some editing this seems like a fine good standalone question; Something like *What software does Wizards of the Coast use to produce its books?* is totally on-topic for this stack. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Thanks in any case for all the links, which are already very useful!

Comment: Might also be a question for Writing.SE

Comment: Agree with @Stackstuck this question, or a version of it, would likely be on-topic at [writing.se](https://writing.stackexchange.com/). I suggest you ask there. If you are asking this to help with formatting homebrew content. The [homebrewery](https://homebrewery.naturalcrit.com/) is a great resource.